# Computer too laggy suddenly with Disk at 100%

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10

I'm running a Windows 10 Pro machine, it is pretty high end, Intel Core i5 6500, 16 GB DRR4 RAM, B150M Mobo, GDDR5 GTX 960 4GB Graphics. However, my PC is very laggy all of a sudden. My disk is always at 100%.

I did a SMART test:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-win10] (sf-6.5-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1000DM003-1SB10C
Serial Number:    W9A1YXHL
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 09b008446
Firmware Version: CC43
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jul 13 18:36:25 2016 SLST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 106) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x1085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   078   063   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       80643330
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       83
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   070   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       11106635
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       269
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       83
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   064   059   040    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 30/36)
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       85
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   036   023   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (0 23 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       80643330
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       267h+52m+30.370s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1465625558
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2297738621

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

[image]
[image]

It literally is very very slow. It used to be fine before but always at 100%. Is my HDD dead? (This is a new hard disk drive, just a month old). Also, would getting a SSD fix this issue?

Comment: An SSD drive would give you faster read/write speeds, but would not remedy the lag.  Show us what processes are running, open task manager and look at both the processes and performance tabs that should help paint a cleaner picture.  Or download a 3rd party app such as Soluto (or many others) that can show you what apps are bogging down your system

Comment: Click on "Open Resource Monitor" (on first screenshot in Task Manager) and see what processes are using the disk.

Comment: Your HD is ok and is working fine. I also have faced it it's not a problem download and install sata controller driver, may be it's already there. You continue to work the transfer rate is automatically adjusted and in the screenshot 113KB is not the limit. The disk transfer rate will be about 100 MBps depending on load.